# What to add a print button dyamnically using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I only want a tiny part of my site to be printable from a button, this is my code but doesn't seem to work to add the button on load to print

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#details ul").append('<li class="print"><a href="#" title="print">Print</a></li>');
});

jQuery('body').on('click','.print',function(){
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=800,width=800');
    var printCSS = jQuery(this).data('print');
    var divContents = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML +
                        "<script>" +
                        "window.onload = function() {" +
                        "     window.print();" +
                        "};" +
                        "<" + "/script>";
    var srcCSS = '<link href=\"print.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\">';
    setTimeout(function() {
        printWindow.document.write( srcCSS + divContents);
        printWindow.document.close();
    }, 250);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why add JS inside HTML? Why not just write the JS...? --- Consider using event listeners.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - To print via JS - you have to create a new window and write your HTML content to it, you then write the JS to it to auto call `window.print()` to trigger the print popup.